# Как правильно сделать перенаправление поисковиков со старых ссылок?

Tags: seo, .htaccess, google-analytics, php

Как правильно сделать перенаправление поисковиков со старых ссылок на новые? Чтобы старые не вылетели с индекса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы заменили cms? 301 редирект Вам в помощь.
http://phpworking.ru/php/301-redirekt-%E2%80%93-gramotnaya-pereadresaciya-htaccess-i-php-header/

Comment: Вылетает 500 ошибка `Redirect 301 /reviews.php http://buket.ru/otzyvy/`